# HttpTimeout gracefully close connection

Tags: java, nginx, tomcat, caching, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using java Apache HttpClient to request a resource (B) with a timeout of 10s. If timeout exceeds Broken pipe is seen at the other application server.

Because of which Nginx at application B is not caching the response. How to gracefully close the connection so that the other app server (B) does not encounter  broken pipe exception.

Comment: What are you grabbing that is taking so long? (i.e. is there a different problem going on?) If it should take ten seconds or close to do download then shouldn't the timeout be higher anyway??.  Surely once you start pulling the data back from B you shouldn't end up with a timeout the packets should be streaming back ...

Comment: You are right, but SLAs are not perfect and sometimes timeout is exceeded and caching layer is not able to cache it while the app server has calculated the response but client has disconnected

Comment: So unless that result is useful to another client - is the caching worth it?

Comment: Server A --> Server B (Heavy operation)  .. Server B is tomcat + Nginx (caching)
if call from server A to B times out. Tomcat of B is throwing broken pipe exception due to client aborting connection. Hence nginx is not able to cache. So, In this case tomcat calculated a valid response but nginx didn't cache it.

Comment: If this was happening on a significant percentage or your calls you'd want to know why / fix it (maybe 10s is too optimistic alot of the time)?  However if it isn't on many then that extra 1% hit might be over-thinking it (optimising something that doesn't need optimising).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using new enough HttpClient can't you do something like this (I just found a snippet someone else had written ... but see below where I've added ###)

```
   HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:8081/test/resource"))
        .header("Accept", "application/json")
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("ping!"))
        .build();

    CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> completableFuture =
        client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    completableFuture
        .completeOnTimeout(DEFAULT_RESPONSE, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)  //  ### ADD THIS the HttpClientRequest actually continues but the future has timed out so the user of the client progresses  ??
        .thenApplyAsync(HttpResponse::headers)
        .thenAcceptAsync(System.out::println);
    HttpResponse<String> response = completableFuture.join();
```